# How should I replant  this daffodil?

Tags: flowers, bulbs, planting, daffodils

[image] While I was transplanting daffodils I came across this plant that grew upside down, with the base of the bulb sticking out of the ground. Now that I dug it up, How should it be replanted?

[image]

Comment: I'd split the difference for this year - plant it sideways.  I'm just guessing.  I've never seen a chthulhudil before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replant it roots down and it might stage a comeback.  The stem will come about.

Comment: The stem has a curve, so it is should be possible to plant it roots down with the stem curving upwards.

Answer (score 3):

Replant it. Most likely it'll come back.

You could toss it. However, just put it back in the ground wherever it came from.